# Bracket axle for Shimano RD-2300 rear derailleur

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear, axle

Where can I find a bracket axle for Shimano RD-2300 rear derailleur? I searched everywhere and I didn't find one. I need to mention that the frame type is Speed Fitness Alloy and bike is a Focus Arriba (2011).

Comment: Do you mean derailleur hanger?

Comment: Yes, a derailleur hanger, but for my specifications

Comment: Wheels Manufacturing database says  you need a #58 derailleur hanger.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you give me a link to see the information please?